# Parsing XML with c++ code

Tags: .net, xml, parsing, c++-cli

Im a .net developer and I have to modify some simple c++ code.

the code fragment is this:

```
rVal = CMgetReportElement("../StatusCode",buffer,1024);

    if(rVal==0)
    {
        dvaResponse->StatusCode  = gcnew String(buffer);
        Int32::TryParse(dvaResponse->StatusCode,functionReturnVal);
    }

return functionReturnVal;
```

it is parsing xml to get the StatusCode (see below) and I think it is failing (I cant debug it)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<TransmissionResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <StatusCode>3002</StatusCode>
</TransmissionResponse>
```

Can someone give me a fail safe way to get the status code out of the xml

I do not know c++ at all so please no pseudocode

the cpp equivalent of :

```
 Regex regex = new Regex("<tag1>(.*)</tag1>");
 var v = regex.Match("morenonxmldata<tag1>0002</tag1>morenonxmldata");
 string s = v.Groups[1].ToString();
```

I have made an attempt now and would appreciate some feedback

```
Regex^ regex = gcnew Regex("<StatusCode>(.*)</StatusCode>");
Match^ match = regex->Match(gcnew String(buffer));
String^ StatusCode = match->Groups[1]->Value;
Int32::TryParse(StatusCode,functionReturnVal);
```

Comment: Why can't you debug it? Do you know how to use `cout`?

Comment: sorry I dont know how to do anything with cpp, It is even compiled inside TFS.  I just need a real simple function to get the value between the StatusCode xml tags

Comment: I'm not familiar with TFS but try adding some `cout` statements, which should output to TFS's console. Something like `cout << "rVal: " << rVal << "\n";` to check if the conditional ever runs.

Comment: You might have trouble getting the addition of `cout` statements to compile if you're not familiar with C++, and explaining everything needed would be to much for a comment and not exactly an answer.

Comment: That's C++/CLI which is closer to C# than to C++, so it's just a matter of syntax. But *please* don't use regexes to parse XML, .NET has a couple decent XML APIs for that, use them.